# Centroids (photutils.centroids) uncertainty

Tags: python, astropy, photutils

There is no way to get the uncertainty from the Centroids (`photutils.centroids`) function. I need to be able to retrieve uncertainty due to using the tool to measure velocities requiring an amount of error to be documented. I have dug through so much documentation and am completely lost. Please help.
https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/centroids.html

It didn't work what do want me to say

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is right.

You have correctly ascertained that that package lacks support
for computing uncertainty from a covariance matrix.

If you choose to send the package maintainer a
[PR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control#Pull_requests)
which adds such a feature, please post an update here.